# what does a variable mean on its own in a python list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, boolean

```
list1 = ["Mike", "", "Emma", "Kelly", "", "Brad"]
[i for i in list1 if i]

['Mike', 'Emma', 'Kelly', 'Brad']
```

Why is it that simply saying "if i" works?

Why doesn't i==True work? Or why doesn't i==False return anything?

I ask because the following code returns a list of booleans:

```
for i in list1:
    print (i != "")


True
False
True
True
False
True
```

Thank you,
R user

Comment: Because **none of the items in the list `== True`. Or `False` for that matter, since they are all strings, and no string is ever equal to a bool

Answer (score 0):

This is because `i` is a string and `True` or `False` is are boolean values.

When you do `if i` it checks wether `i` is an empty string and if not it returns `True`.

But when you check `if i == True` it checks whether the value of `i` is a boolean value and whether its `True`. In your case it will always resolve to `False` since `i` is a string and does not hold a boolean value.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated that. Simple example: `1 == True` returns `True`.

Comment: But that's because in Python3 boolean type is a subtype of integer type and the boolean values `False` and `True` are mapped to 0 and 1 respectively.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-10